# Tracking view count real time, increment, decrement as users come and go

Tags: php, view, memcached

I want to track view counts in real time. That means increment view count for a web page when a user comes, and decrement the count when a user leaves. I am using PHP 7. I was thinking about using **memcached** for this, to keep it as fast as possible. The view count must be displayed on the web page for everyone to see.

I want to use Ajax requests to get view count every N seconds. But the problem is: **how do you know when to decrement / how do you know when a user 'leaves'?**
I was thinking about using PHP sessions because they expire after some time, maybe I can set a session for 30 seconds, and if during that time, no Ajax requests are received, that means the user is gone and view count must be decremented.

Or: in memcached it's possible to set a TTL for the key-value? Maybe I can use that to let it expire. But I would need to differentiate between users that are currently on the web page, so that it would be possible to expire the key-value of that user when the user is gone.

So how to differentiate between users? Users' PHP session IDs. Save in memcached like:

```
$pageid = "page123";
$sessionid = session_id();
$key = $pageid . $sessionid;
$memcached->set($key, null);
```

So each saved record is a view. To get total amount of views, I need to retrieve all records from memcached, to count them and display it.

How can I solve this, I would appreciate any tips. I have seen a lot of suggestions, but most of them are about regular view counts and not real time.

Answer (score 0):

try using ajax on:

```
<body onLoad="{{ajax function to increment}}"> 
<body onunload="{{ajax function to decrements}}">
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this just now, unload and beforeunload events seem to work half of the time in Chrome and do not work in Firefox. Seems to be unreliable.